# A simpler proof of the continuity equivalence between norm and weak topologies

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, dual-spaces, weak-topology

I'm trying to simplify the proof of Theorem 3.10 in Brezis' book of Functional Analysis. My proof is much simpler than the original. I'm afraid that I made subtle mistakes. Could you have a check on my attempt?

> Let $E,F$ be Banach spaces and $E^\star, F^\star$ their continuous dual spaces respectively. Let $\sigma (E, E^\star)$ be the weak topology of $E$. We denote by $E_w$ and $E_s$ the space $E$ with the weak and norm topologies respectively. We do similarly for $F$. Let $T: E \to F$ be linear. If $T:E_w \to F_w$ is continuous, then $T:E_s \to F_s$ is continuous.

Let $\sigma (E, E^\star) \boxtimes \sigma (F, F^\star)$ be the product topology of $\sigma (E, E^\star)$ and $\sigma (F, F^\star)$. Then the author uses the fact that $$\sigma (E, E^\star) \boxtimes \sigma (F, F^\star) = \sigma \big (E \times F, (E \times F)^\star \big).$$

Below I propose my simpler approach. We say "weakly" (resp. "strongly") to refer to topological concepts in weak (resp. norm) topology.

Let $T : E_w \to F_w$ be continuous. Then $\operatorname{graph} T$ is weakly closed in the product of weak topologies. Let $(x_n, y_n)$ be a sequence in $\operatorname{graph} T$ such that $(x_n, y_n) \to (x,y)$ strongly. Then $x_n \to x$ strongly and $y_n \to y$ strongly. Then $x_n \to x$ weakly and $y_n \to y$ weakly. Then $(x_n, y_n) \to (x,y)$ weakly. Then $(x,y) \in \operatorname{graph} T$ and thus $\operatorname{graph} T$ is strongly closed in the product of norm topologies. The claim then follows from closed graph theorem.

Comment: Knowing that the weak and the original topology have the same bounded sets and that continuity between normed spaces is the same as mapping bounded sets to bounded sets, you do not need the closed graph theorem. The results holds for normed (and more generally, for *bornological locally convex*) spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally fine to me: indeed note that when you say that "$(x_n, y_n) \to (x,y)$ strongly, then $x_n \to x$ strongly and $y_n \to y$ strongly" you are exactly using properties of the product topology.